# Toggle Sprint Not working correctly Minecraft 1.8.8 MCP

Tags: java, minecraft

I am having an issue to get my toggle sprint to properly function, it will work, but the second I move backwards and try to move forward again it stops doing what it is intended to do, but don't want to get banned for using it as it is not intended to be used for hacks, I have this code:

```
package me.Kishiyami.ecstasy.module.movement;

import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;

import me.Kishiyami.ecstasy.module.Category;
import me.Kishiyami.ecstasy.module.Module;

public class AutoSprint extends Module{

    public AutoSprint() {
        super("AutoSprint", Keyboard.KEY_K, Category.MOVEMENT);
    }
    
    public void onEnable() {
        if(this.isToggled()) {
            mc.thePlayer.setSprinting(true);
            super.onEnable();
        }
    }
    
    public void onDisable() {
        mc.thePlayer.setSprinting(false);
        super.onDisable();
    }
    
}
```

So I was wondering if anybody else has had this issue before and if they know a better way to do this?

I have tried to change some of the code to work with all movement keys, I expected it to stay sprinting after I press w again, but it does not continue the sprinting and goes back to walking.